# Help my toilet doesn't Flush completely the first time or second time

Tags: toilet

Please tell me what steps to take to get my toilet to flush completely the first time.

Comment: Offhand, I suggest you hold down the handle longer.

Comment: I replaced the crazy old toilets in my house with some new Kohlers. They're glazed around the bend so things move better over the trap. It also has a horizontal jet to push things down. Probably takes less water than whatever you have at present

Answer (score 2):

- educate kids/occupants not to put anything into the toilet bowl other than

  - normal bodily excreta.
  - *minimal* amounts of toilet paper. (n.b. wet-wipes etc can cause partial blockages)
- check the fill level in the cistern/tank, adjust as needed.
- replace the flush valves in the cistern/tank.
- clean out the inlet holes around the rim.
- use a limescale remover in the bowl and in the tank.
- snake the sewer pipe.
- replace the whole thing.

Comment: You might add, - Use less paper. - Eat more fiber.  It's not always a problem with the toilet.